# With the Paladin's Divine Smite, can you expend spell slots over 4th?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, paladin

If I multiclass Caster 18/Paladin 2, could I use higher than 4th level spell slots to use Divine Smite, even if I gain no bonuses to damage for doing so?

Comment: [Related] [What is the maximum damage done by Divine Smite?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57077/what-is-the-maximum-damage-done-by-divine-smite)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no restriction on which spell slots you can use, only on the damage dealt. The maximum is only mentioned in the second sentence, which is entirely about damage and doesn't ever mention spell slots. You can use a higher level spell slot with Divine Smite, but, as you say, it will only deal the 5d8.