# Is there a feat akin to the Fighter's Action Surge which is available to other classes?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, paladin

While reading the comments of [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/57078/10052), I came across the following statement :

> ... if you still have 5 slots you can still use the [Divine] Smite 5× in a round
> (with 2 attacks, **times two with a feat**, and one bonus attack) ...

What **feat** could the commenter be referring to?

I am aware of the **Fighter**'s 2nd level class feature, **[Action Surge](https://dnd5e.fandom.com/wiki/Fighter#Action_Surge)**, but am not aware of a **feat** available to other classes ( specifically **Paladin** ) that grants the quoted "times two with a feat" effect/ability.

I've looked through my PHB's feats section and don't see anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## There is no such feat

You are not missing anything, the commenter was mistaken.

I have seen many people use "feat" instead of "feature"; he might have meant Action Surge too.

Comment: I thought not; thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

## You can't get Action Surge or similar as a feat

As [Andras correctly states](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138394/48759), there is no 5e feat that allows this; there is also no 5e feat that will grant more than 1 additional attack per turn. Any feat that does grant an additional attack (Great Weapon Master, Crossbow Expert, etc.) does so using your bonus action, so they don't stack and you can only ever get 1 additional attack.

Additionally, allowing a feat that grants effects similar to Action Surge would be extremely overpowered. Every single class can benefit from it, and would all take it at the first opportunity if it did exist. Action Surge is so good that many people consider the 2-level dip into fighter to be a worthwhile investment for it alone.

#### Previous Editions

It is possible they were confusing feats from previous editions. I have often seen the Pathfinder feat "Improved Two-Weapon Fighting" referred to as doubling your attacks, as it allows an additional off-hand attack for each of your main attacks.

Comment: Yes, understood. Just to clarify, I was not asking whether Action Surge was a feat or not, but rather whether there existed a feat _similar_ to it. I tried to make that distinction by calling out that Action Surge is a Fighter's 2nd level **class** feature.

Comment: @CodeMaverick My point was to show that there was similar feats in earlier editions but not 5th. I'll adjust the wording.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Pathfinder's Two-Weapon Fighting feat doesn't enable you to make off-hand attacks, since you can already do that. It just reduces the otherwise prohibitive penalty. Granted, off-hand attacks are rather ineffective without the feat, so this is just me being pedantic.

Comment: @BBeast it allows you to make an additional off hand attack. Without it you can only make 1 off-hand attack. Technically it's Improved Two-Weapon Fighting so I'll change my answer.

Comment: @linksassin double-checking the SRD, it appears that Improved and Greater TWF grant extra off-hand attacks, whereas regular TWF refers to the standard 1 off-hand attack (although the flavour text makes this ambiguous). Although if you want to discuss further I'll be in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).